# Jenkins job to release all Maven projects

Tags: maven, jenkins, release

Just curious about is it possible to release all the Maven projects through one Jenkins job build? Thanks for any help

Comment: What do you mean by "all maven projects"? Are you referring to multiple jobs configured on the Jenkins, and releasing them at the same time?

Comment: Yes. That's what I am asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can have an additional POM with modules corresponding to your jobs.

It's slightly different compared to what ajozwik proposed to you, so we might need more info to see what fits your needs best.